# Is reference to an array exactly the same as the array name in C++

Tags: c++, arrays

With reference to the following code, I have some queries :

```
main() {
    int i[10] ;
    int * const&rp = i ; 
    cout<<rp<<" "<<i<<" "<<&i<<" "<<&rp<<endl ;

    int a ; int &b = a ; 
    cout<<&a<<" "<<&b<<endl ;
}
```

Following is a typical output :

```
0xbff62298 0xbff62298 0xbff62298 0xbff622c0
0xbff622c4 0xbff622c4
```

Now what I really can not explain is this :

1. Addresses of `a` and `b` are the same, that is `&a` and `&b` return the same result
2. But `&i` and `&rp` return different results

Why is it so

Comment: `rp` is reference to pointer, not reference to array. It refers to a temporary object that points to the array's first element. `int (&rp)[10] = i;` would refer to the array and give the expected behaviur

Comment: `b` is reference of `a` and reference is not an object so it doesn't have its own memory location. References are bounded to the object.

Comment: Yes @M.M I got the point. Thanx

Comment: Just on second thoughts @M.M would the following two functions have different treatment : `void f(int (&x)[10]) {}
void g(int (x)[10]) {}`

Comment: Pretty much, in the same way that a reference to an `int` is pretty much exactly the same as the `int`'s name in C++.

Comment: @user3282758 yes those are different the second one is *adjusted* to be `int *x`,, this is something that only happens in function parameters

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Addresses of `a` and `b` are the same, that is `&a` and `&b` return the same result

A reference is not an object. It does not have an address. When you apply addressof operator on a reference, you ask for the address of the referred object. Since `b` refers to `a`, you get the same address.

> But `&i` and `&rp` return different results

This is because `rp` does not refer to the array `i`. It refers to a temporary pointer object that you created implicitly when you bound the reference.

> Is reference to an array exactly the same as the array name in C++

Perhaps not exactly, but almost. Both the variable name and the reference are an alias of the object. Same applies to references of all types.